# Ionic/Cordova. Save image to photo gallery

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have a URLs to external PNG images. I want to download it directly to Camera Roll (iOS) or Photo Gallery(Android). How I can manage it with Ionic

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I am looking for the exact same solution but haven't found one.

Comment: Yes. Canvas2Image plugin.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
```

add file link in index.

```
 <script src="js/ng-cordova.js"></script>
 <script src="js/FileTransferController.js"></script>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.downloadFile = function() {
        var url = "http://your_ip_address/images/my.png";
        var filename = url.split("/").pop();
        alert(filename);
        var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + filename;
        var trustHosts = true
        var options = {};
        alert(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory);
        $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
            .then(function(result) {
                // Success!
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            }, function(error) {
                // Error
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }, function (progress) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
                })
            });
    }
```

From [HERE](http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2015/03/file-upload-download-with-ng-cordova.html)

hope its helpful to someone.

Comment: Will it download to app's filesystem or to Camera Roll?

Comment: This code will store inages in Internal Storage inside app

Comment: Is it possible to store image into camera roll ?